# Invalidating ASP.NET FormsAuthentication server side

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am experimenting with FormsAuthentication (using ASP.NET MVC2) and it is working fairly well.

However, one case I can't work out how to deal with is validating the user identity on the server to ensure it is still valid from the *server's* perspective.

eg.

1. User logs in ... gets a cookie/ticket
2. Out of band the user is deleted on the server side
3. User makes a new request to the server.  HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is set to the deleted user.

I can *detect* this fine, but what is the correct way to handle it?  Calling `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` in the `OnAuthorization` on `OnActionExecuting` events is too late to affect the current request.

Alternatively I would like to be able to calls FormsAuthentication.InvalidateUser(...) when the user is deleted (or database recreated) to invalidate all tickets for a given (or all) users.  But I can't find an API to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the global.asax, add an handler for `AuthenticateRequest`. In this method, the forms authentication has already taken place and you're free to modify the current principal before anything else happens.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  IPrincipal principal = HttpContext.Current.User;
  if (!UserStillValid(principal)) {
    IPrincipal anonymousPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(String.Empty), null);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = anonymousPrincipal;
    HttpContext.Current.User = anonymousPrincipal;
  }     
}
```

Just implement the `UserStillValid` method and you're done. It's also a good place to swap the generic principal with a custom one if you need to.

Comment: UserStillValid function will check the user is active in db or not?  what is the meaning of Thread.CurrentPrincipal = anonymousPrincipal and HttpContext.Current.User = anonymousPrincipal;