# Fill my model of m viewModel in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I try to fill my model that is member of view model, 
I send data from Action to view.It's work correct. but when click on save button, get an error that

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The view model is

```
public class OrderCustomer
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

And action for post data is

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(OrderCustomer values)
    {
        var orderCustomer = new OrderCustomer();
        var order = orderCustomer.Order;

        string uId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
        order.ApplicationUserId = uId;
        order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
        order.Address = values.ApplicationUser.Address;
        order.CityId = (int)values.ApplicationUser.CityId;
        order.CountryId = (int)values.ApplicationUser.CountryId;
        order.Email = values.ApplicationUser.Email;
        order.FirstName = values.ApplicationUser.FName;
        order.LastName = values.ApplicationUser.LName;
        order.Phone = values.ApplicationUser.Phone;
        order.PostalCode = values.ApplicationUser.PostalCode;
        order.ProvinceId = (int)values.ApplicationUser.ProvinceId;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            TryUpdateModel(order);

            try
            {
                _db.Orders.Add(order);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                cart.CreateOrder(order);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Payment", new { id = order.Id });

            }
            catch
            {
               return View(order);
            }
        }
        return View(order);


    }
```

when debugger arrive on this code show the error line 5 in above code that show in below, how can i fix it?

```
        order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: maybe the request is not authenticated so there is no identity set - look into your auth code or set an anonymous principal like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893334/invalidating-asp-net-formsauthentication-server-side

Comment: `order` is `null`. you do not assign an instance to that property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `OrderCustomer` does not initialize `Order` when it is initialized

like

```
public class OrderCustomer {

    public OrderCustomer () {
        Order = new Order();
    }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

then `Order` would be `null` by default.

This would mean that currently you create an instance of `OrderCustomer` but never assign a value to the `Order` property.

```
 var orderCustomer = new OrderCustomer();
 var order = orderCustomer.Order; //<-- Order is null by default
```

Thus `order` is `null` as you do not assign a object to that variable.

So either refactor to example above or make sure to create a new instance.

```
var orderCustomer = new OrderCustomer() {
    Order = new Order()
};

var order = orderCustomer.Order;
//...code removed for brevity
```

This however now begs the question why you are not assigning that value from what was posted as part of the view model?

I believe this is what you intended

```
var order = values.Order;
```